# Python weird new line character in text file

Tags: python, string, utf

I have another program, (that I don't have the source code to) that writes to a text file, then when I try to read the text file like this,

```
with open("domain.com/alive_domains.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

the output is something like this: (This was copy and pasted straight from pycharm's console window)

```
http://stage.oidc.payments.domain.com

https://oidc.help.domain.com

https://search.domain.com

https://oidc.payments.domain.com

https://stage.oidc.payments.domain.com

http://stage.oidc.help.domain.com

https://stage.oidc.help.domain.com
```

for some reason there are weird new line characters, that I don't think are new lines

I tried to fix this by doing something like

---

```
abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz:/."

def fix_string(s):
    new_s = ""
    for char in s:
        if char in abc:
            new_s += char
    return ''.join(new_s)

with open("domain.com/alive_domains.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(fix_string(line))
```

And I got the same output..

---

I tried googling, and came across this regex

```
   with open("domain.com/alive_domains.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            line = re.sub("[^a-z0-9/.:]+","", line, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
            print(fix_string(line))
```

And again, it gave me the same output with the new lines

It doesn't do it with any other file I try to read line by line. Is there a way to identify the weird char? If there is one

Comment: If you think there is a weird character being read from the file, try running `[ord(c) for c in line]` and check for values outside the expected ASCII range.

Comment: @Brian Okay, just tried, seems to be fine, it seems to have it's own line (?) As in when I loop through the lines, it's every other line, so line 1 will be the URL, then line 2 is blank, even when I try to do [ord(c) for c in line], it gives me an empty array with no items inside of it

Comment: Even though I don't see a blank line, on line 2, in the file

Comment: But I can just check the line's length... I guess

Answer (score 2):

Each line you read from the input file is a string that is already terminated by a newline character. When you write these strings to the output file, [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) adds yet another newline character to the output, resulting in the double newlines.

To suppress this behavior, write

```
print(some_string, end='')
```

Alternatively, if you don't need the added functionality of `print`, you can write to the file handle directly via

```
f.write(some_sring)
```

Comment: Right, but my if you look at my output from pycharm's command line, it's one new line from print, then another new line from somewhere else

Comment: @leak Each line you read from the file is a string that is already terminated by a newline character. When you write these strings to the output file, `print` adds yet another newline character to the output, resulting in the double newlines. I update my answer to make this more clear

Comment: I tried print(line, end="") before, and I just retried it to make sure it was what I got before, Instead of doing two new lines like before, It just prints them in all one line I.E `http://stage.oidc.payments.domain.comhttps://oidc.help.domain.com` @Brian

Comment: very weird, I've never seen this.